# How to use "\" not as a command but just as a text in a string

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a graphic in C++ that basically is a smiley face:

"_____/"

But when I build my program, the use of "\" character gives me an error "unknown escape sequence"

Any thoughts? I am going to print the smiley face by printing some special characters.

Comment: Consider looking into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site, reading some good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book, and later the [C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) to get the answer to such basic questions. Be also aware that [UTF-8 is everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) in 2018

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have to [escape](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) the backslash itself. Try using `\\`.

Comment: You're welcome! More info on escape sequences: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Answer (score 1):

Use "\\" . The backslash is a string command

```
"\\" --> \
"\n" --> new line
"\t" --> tab
```

etc..

See full list here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Comment: Same answer as [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397996/841108) one (4 minutes earlier than yours)

Comment: Yes, looks like we were writing at the same minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use raw string literals in C++11 that is more convenient:

```
std::cout << "The output is: " << R"(\_________/)" << std::endl;
```

that prints for you something like this:

```
The output is: \_________/
```